# TimeSpan not giving expected results

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan

I am trying to log how long certain methods take within my ASP.Net application. On my services calls, I have a base class that has StartTimer and StopTimer methods.

The idea is that I can start a timer, record a start time, and then stop the timer, getting the current date and working out the difference.

```
public class ServiceBase
{
  private DateTime _timerValue;
  private string _message;

  public string StartTimer(string message)
  {
    _message = message;
    _timerValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
    return string.Format("Started {0} at {1}", _message, _timerValue.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff"));
  }

  public string StopTimer()
  {
    var dateNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var t = dateNow - _timerValue;
    var time = t.Milliseconds;
    return string.Format("Completed {0} - {1}ms at {2}", _message, time, dateNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff"));
  }

}
```

This is called from the methods within my main class like this:

```
public UserDto ValidateUser(UserDto user)
{
    Logger.Info(StartTimer(string.Format("ValidateUser({0})", user.Username)));
    var reply = _ub.ValidateUser(user);
    Logger.Info(StopTimer());
    return reply;
}
```

However, I am not getting the expected result in my log file. For example, look here:

[image]

Note the last Start/Stop.

Started GetSprints(2) at **19:59:01.4988**
Completed GetSprints(2) - **531ms** at **19:59:03.0301**

It's saying that the difference between 19:59:01.4988 and 19:59:03.0301 is only 531ms - which is incorrect.

Update:

Thanks to the answers, my new code looks like this, and seems to work:

```
public class ServiceBase
    {
        private string _message;
        private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch;

        public ServiceBase()
        {
            _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        }

        public string StartTimer(string message)
        {
            _message = message;
            _stopwatch.Start();
            return string.Format("Started {0}", _message);
        }

        public string StopTimer()
        {
            _stopwatch.Stop();
            return string.Format("Completed {0} - {1}ms", _message, _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

    }
```

Not sure why I got a -1 vote though - I thought it was a good question that will hopefully assist others.

Comment: Any reason for not using `Stopwatch` ?

Comment: Why do you know it's incorrect? What should the value be?

Comment: Only reason would be because I never knew of this. Is it a more suitable thing to use?

Comment: I think I just spotted the error. t.Millisecond, I think, only brings back the Millisecond portion. I think I need to say t.Seconds * 1000 + t.Milliseconds... Testing.

Comment: @Craig of course to measure time exactly, `Stopwatch` is needed, `Timer` is not enough.

Comment: @Craig right way but you can use TotalMilliseconds to get the value of the TimeSpan expressed in milliseconds without any other calculation.

Comment: Moreover you may consider Stopwatch if you need exact calculations, system timer resolution is pretty **variable** and not accurate at all (but if 50 ms granularity isn't a problem then you can go on with that).

Comment: @Adriano - thanks man! I did it with my calculation, and it works now... and now, I will improve it with .TotalMilliseconds. Thanks.

Comment: @Craig You need to use `timespan.TotalMilliSeconds` `timespan.Millisecond` will always be lesser than `1000`

Answer (score 2):

You want `t.TotalMilliseconds`, no `t.Milliseconds`.  If you don't include Total, then you are only getting the Millisecond component of the `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var time = t.Milliseconds;
```

Should be...

```
 var time = t.TotalMilliseconds;
```